# Google maps marker doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am attempting to implement a marker, putting it at various locations, but it isn't showing up. However, it does center on the place.

**This is the Javascript I'm trying:**

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

var map;
var markers = [
    ['Kapelstraat 13', 52.408421,6.896036,21],
];

function initMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        draggable: true,
        panControl: false,
        scrollwheel: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.408421,6.896036,21)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    setMarkers();
}

function setMarkers(){
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var post = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: post,
            map: map
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: markers[i][0]
        });

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
}
```

**I did use this link to link the map:**

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [The posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zbvajphn/) (it displays a marker).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I had to delete **async defer** out of this script. It solved the problem, thanks everyone anyway

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

```
var markers = [
    ['Kapelstraat 13', 52.408421,6.896036,21],
];
```

Try this:

```
var markers = ['Kapelstraat 13', 52.408421,6.896036,21];
```

The comma and extra brackets are only necessary if you are making an array of arrays. If that is your goal, then you need to add another array of marker data and NOT end the list of arrays with a comma. Otherwise it is prompted to look for the next array, and not finding one it likely is just throwing an error in your console.